# Need to find how to create a floating header

Tags: html, css, web

it's my first time here, I'm looking for a way to do a kind of floating header in HTML or CSS.
I mean you know that kind of websites when you scroll down a part of the page follow you.
Just like this : 
https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/YqLyXB

> Blockquote
>
> `ea`

Hope the question isn't asking anywhere else, It's hard to find out a response in english since I can barely explain it my french!
Thank's if you take time to answer.

Comment: Well sorry guys I was trying to avoid putting code so I've added that weird "blockquote ea",

Comment: If someone can still help it would be gratefull.

Comment: `position: fixed;`? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMgMPR

Comment: Wow thank's a lot mate, perfect answer :)!

Comment: no problem! Would you like me to submit that as an answer?

Comment: Yes of course, even if my post is a little ugly right?

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed;` will create a header that is "fixed" to the top of the window viewport and will float over the rest of the site's content.

```css
body {
  height: 500vh;
  background: url('http://www.platonphoto.com/photos/72-1057-a.jpg') top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `position: fixed`.

It is one of the positioning available for a HTML element which allows you to take a certain element out of the normal flow of your document and make it fixed at a certain place. Then it won't scroll as you scroll the image.